# Can I create software for Microsoft Windows in visual studio using Java

Tags: java

I have been learning java recently and is using eclipse as IDE. But , I am not able to make a .exe file with that . all I get is jar file which I know can be executed on the window machine. My question is that can I use Visual studio and create .exe program or for that matter any software for Microsoft Windows using Java ?

Comment: [exe4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/exe4j/files), [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/), [jsmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/),  [jwrapper](http://www.jwrapper.com/java-to-exe-free.html)

Comment: The short answer is, no, you can't use VS to create executables based on the Java language. The longer answer is you can use any number of exe wrappers to make a nice (windows) executable which wrap around your class/jar files